# Tomcat takes too long to start

Tags: apache, tomcat

When I try to start the Apache tomcat server (version 8.5.11) on my PC (Windows 10) , the loading process is always stuck after loading validation properties.

[image: screenshot]

It sometimes forever for the server to run. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does it hang at that point, or does it continue after some time. if so what are the next lines?

Comment: @muttonUp Yes, it runs the necessary web-apps files and starts normally. After Loading valiation properties, the following message shows up:                                                                                                             31-Mar-2017 15:54:06.428 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
31-Mar-2017 15:54:06.456 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
31-Mar-2017 15:54:06.465 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 65446 ms

Comment: If there are no errors, or warnings between the messages then that is probably the startup time. tomcat webapps, can do a lot of work at startup depending on the libraries used. But once running all the initialisation work has been done and startup times are not indicative of performance.

Comment: There are messages showing loading of files .. An Example of these message is                                                                                          "31-Mar-2017 15:54:04.875 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Apache\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\examples"
There are numerous messages like this. Anyway,  I have understood your point and resolved my issue . Thank you for your help @muttonUp.

Comment: If you have resolved your problem, then add your solution as an answer, otherwise how will this question help anyone in future? Thanks.

Comment: @AnchitSrivastava Can you please add the solution you found as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

To decrease the startup time of tomcat 9 I simply added this option in the JAVA_OPTS

-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom